# Justify node text in DiagrammeR

Tags: r, diagrammer

Does anybody know if `DiagrammeR` currently supports left- and right-justification of node labels when using GraphViz?

Here is a quick example, where I would like to left-justify the text within both of the nodes:

```
library(DiagrammeR)
grViz("
  digraph test {
    graph [fontsize = 10]

    node [shape = box]
    A [label = 'Foo\nBar']
    B [label = 'Bar\nFoo']

    A -> B
  }
")
```

I was able to find one resource [here](http://www.graphviz.org/content/attrs#kescString) for the native GraphViz that uses `/l` for left-justification, but when I try that within the `grViz` function I receive an error.  For example:

```
library(DiagrammeR)
grViz("
digraph test {
  graph [fontsize = 10]

  node [shape = box]
    A [label = 'Foo\lBar']
    B [label = 'Bar\lFoo']

  A -> B
}
")
```

I appreciate any help in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a double backslash to escape the first slash. Here are left and right justified labels:

```
grViz("
  digraph test {
    graph [fontsize = 10]

    node [shape = box]
    A [label = 'Foo\\lBar\\l']
    B [label = 'Bar\\rFoo\\r']

    A -> B
  }
")
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you @eipi10!  I figured it was something silly like this that I was overlooking.