# diagrammeR/GraphViz - justify node text if node text is multi-line substitution label

Tags: r, rstudio, graphviz, diagrammer

I am using substitution labels (@@) with diagrammeR and Graphviz syntax. I have seen previous questions about justification of node labels such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34534018/justify-node-text-in-diagrammer) when the labels are in-line text, but I am wondering how to justify node text generated from a multi-row substitution label. More specifically, for the label in the reproducible example below, I want the ‘main’ column, meaning the first and third rectangle labels, to remain centered, but multi-line node labels such as the rightmost rectangle to be left justified (the value as well as the subvalues). Since I specify line breaks in the substitution labels, I tried using double backslash \l instead of \n without success. 
Additionally, I would like to bold the headers (in the reproducible example, the first value, second value, and third value rows), but not bold any subvalues. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
library(DiagrammeR)
library(DiagrammeRsvg)

a <- 100
x <- 50
b <- 30
d <- 20


grViz("

                      digraph a_nice_graph {

                      node[fontname = Helvetica, shape = box, width = 4, fontcolor = darkslategray]
                      firstvalue[label = '@@1']
                      secondvalue[label = '@@2']
                      thirdvalue[label = '@@3']
                      blank[label = '', width = 0.01, height = 0.01]
                      { rank = same; blank secondvalue }
                      firstvalue -> blank [dir = none] 
                      blank -> secondvalue[minlen = 9]
                      blank -> thirdvalue
                      }
                      [1]: paste0('First value (n = ', a, ')')
                      [2]: paste0('Second value (n = ', a-x, ')\\nSubvalue = ', b, '\\nSubvalue = ', d, '')
                      [3]: paste0('Third value (n = ', x, ')')
                      ")
```